# How to print default value of class object when using setters and getters

Tags: python

this is my code and i want to print the default value of name - "no name", but when i try it it says : AttributeError: 'Warriors' object has no attribute '_Warriors__name'. how can i fix it?

```
class Warriors:
    def __init__(self, name="no name"):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        if value.isalpha():
            self.__name = value
        else:
            print("Something went wrong")

test1 = Warriors()
print(test1.name)
```

Comment: `'Warriors' object has no attribute '_Warriors__name'.`, you need to define that inside the constructor. See this [repl](https://repl.it/repls/DazzlingUselessDesigners).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor should be like:

```
class Warriors:
    def __init__(self, name="no name"):
        self.__name = name
```

Comment: i dont realy get what does that "__" change (i am newb) but it works and thanks :D do you have any source where it is well explained?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/implementing_java-style_getters_and_setters.html?highlight=property

Answer (score 2):

Your approach goes though the following flow:

- `test1 = Warriors()` calls the initializer method `__init__(self, name="no name")`:
- `__init__` performs `self.name = name` which is then causing setter `@name.setter` invocation:
- the `@name.setter` performs the check `if value.isalpha():` which **fails** because `"no name"` is not completely an alpha sequence. That's why `self.__name = value` will not be initialized
- then, the line `print(test1.name)` tries to access `name` causing calling getter `def name(self): return self.__name` which can't find a particular attribute - and that's a reason of `'Warriors' object has no attribute '_Warriors__name'` error

---

If proceeding with your current approach you may just set the default value in `setter` method as below:

```
...
@name.setter
def name(self, value):
    if value.isalpha():
        self.__name = value
    else:
        self.__name = 'no name'
        print("Something went wrong")
```

Or assigning the internal attribute value on initializing phase:

```
...
def __init__(self, name="no name"):
    self.__name = name
```